# Анимация блока при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать анимацию блоков, которые прижаты к правому краю браузера?

У нас есть блоки (ссылки) на определенные якоря на странице, т.е. выглядит как переключатели страниц.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/rjr6gaqo/)

```
    .pages {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.pages a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f8b10a;
    color: #000;
    /*padding: 11px 20px;*/
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Как реализовать анимацию увеличения блока влево при наведении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `margin` не подойдет?

```
.pages a:hover {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Чувствую себя идиотом. Голова уже блин не работает к вечеру пятницы(